# Why does this ruby use \u001 for 1 and how to change?

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

I've written the classic fizzbuzz code.

The spec:

```
describe "can determine fizzbuxx output for" do
  it "3" do
    expect(Fizzbuzz.nums(3)).to eq "123fizz"
  end 
end
```

The code:

```
class Fizzbuzz
  def self.nums(n)
    result=""
    (1..n).each do |inner|
      puts "inner #{inner}"
      result << inner
      if (inner % 3)==0
        result << 'fizz'
      end
      if (inner % 5)==0
        result << 'buzz'
      end
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Why am I getting `\u001`... instead of `1`?

```
Failures:

1) can determine fizzbuxx output for 3
 Failure/Error: expect(Fizzbuzz.nums(3)).to eq "123fizz"

   expected: "123fizz"
        got: "\u0001\u0002\u0003fizz"

   (compared using ==)
 # ./fizzbuzz_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is it some sort of utf-8 issue?

Comment: Probably has to do with the fact you use `<<` with a `Fixnum`. Changing it to `result << inner.to_s` produces the desired result. I'm sure somebody can dig up the exact behavior and provide a better explanation.

Comment: Yes that worked.  Post as an answer and I'll accept. thx

Comment: From [`String#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C): *"Concatenates the given object to str. If the object is a `Integer`, it is considered as a codepoint, and is converted to a character before concatenation."*

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Stefan's explanation plus my fix is the answer, I see there already is an answer mentioning the `.to_s` solution so I won't post it again. At least it is solved now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby for string [`concatenation: <<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C), if the object is an Integer, it is considered as a codepoint, and is converted to a character before concatenation. And since Ruby 1.9 default encoding is UTF-8. The codepoints are forced to be encoded with UTF-8:

```
1.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
# => "\u0001"
```

So, when you're doing this:

```
"" << 1
```

Ruby actually consider `1` as a codepoint and try to convert it to string with UTF-8 encoding, and will actually does this instead:

```
"" << 1.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
#=> "\u0001"
```

So, to solve your problem. You can explicitly convert Fixnum to String by changing code to:

```
result << inner.to_s
```

or with String interpolation:

```
result << "#{inner}"
```

Answer (score 3):

It is the expected behaviour of the `String#<<` method. From the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3C-3C):

> Concatenates the given object to str. If the object is a Integer, it is considered as a codepoint, and is converted to a character before concatenation.

You have to explicitly convert the integer to a string before appending:

```
'' << 1 # => "\u0001"
'' << 1.to_s => "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

For small numbers their type is a [FixNum](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Fixnum.html) [ Holds Integer values that can be represented in a native machine word (minus 1 bit). ]

```
result << inner
```

Explicitly convert it to a String and you'll get the results you want.

```
result << inner.to_s
```