# push to string and separate values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `arr = [1,2,3,4,5..etc]`

```
str = ''
arr.each do|a|
 str << a
end
```

I need `str='1,2,3..etc'`

Instead of `str='123'`

in short I need add separator between  values

Comment: where is `4` in the final output ?

Comment: does not matter,it can be huge array.All what i want add separator when pushing new value to str

Comment: Well if your roughy translate your statement into ruby then this is what you come up with `arr.join(",")` ie. join the array by a separator :)

Comment: @Katya : Arup's answer is correct. However, your code output `str='123'` is incorrect. As if you concat a Fixnum to a String then it'll be treated as a codepoint and your string should be something like: `str= '\u0001..'` etc.. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26405181/645886 to know what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Array#join` method.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5..9]
arr.join(',')
```